# Nginx PHP-FPM access logs shows 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I'm using Nginx and passing all requests for .php to PHP-FPM.

How do I get PHP-FPM's access logs to show the real client ip address instead of 127.0.0.1?

php-fpm-access.log

```
127.0.0.1 -  25/Sep/2021:18:51:03 -0700 "GET /test.php" 200
127.0.0.1 -  25/Sep/2021:18:51:03 -0700 "GET /test.php" 200
127.0.0.1 -  25/Sep/2021:18:54:42 -0700 "GET /test.php" 200
```

nginx vhost

```
location ~* \.php {
    try_files       $uri =404;
    include         /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   X-REAL-IP           $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param   X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

php-fpm pool

```
[domain]

user = www
group = www

listen = 127.0.0.1:9001

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 10
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60
pm.max_requests = 500

access.log = /var/log/php-fpm-access.log

php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
```

nginx fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to get Nginx to log the PHP access requests to a separate file. Then the PHP-FPM backend can focus solely on processing the PHP requests - and nothing else.

This works well for me :

```
location ~* \.php {
        try_files       $uri =404;
        access_log      /var/log/php-fpm/php-access.log main;
        include         /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        include         /usr/local/etc/nginx/php-fpm.conf;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
}
```